# In a table partitioned BY LIST (n), how can I quickly SELECT MAX(n) without an index?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I created a MyISAM table that stores rows in different partitions based on the `year` column, with each year given its own partition, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
, year SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED
, ...
, PRIMARY KEY (id, year)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
PARTITION BY LIST (year) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (2000)
, PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (2001)
, ...
);
```

The question I want to answer is simple; what's the greatest value of `year` in the table? In other words:

```
SELECT MAX(year) FROM t;
```

It seems, from looking at the table definition, that there should be an execution plan for this query that runs in constant time *without* reordering the PK or creating a new index on `year`. All the database needs to do is find the partition that's defined as having the maximum value, and then check whether any rows exist in that partition; if not, check the next largest, and so on. Unfortunately, the optimizer chooses instead to do a full table scan.

I can easily query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to find the largest value of `year` for which there is a defined partition:

```
SELECT MAX(PARTITION_DESCRIPTION)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't';
```

However, that only tells me about the partitions defined on the table, not the rows that exist in the table; if some partitions could be empty, it's not necessarily going to give me the `MAX(year)`. I tried adding an `EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT MAX(PARTITION_DESCRIPTION)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't'
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM fact_registration 
               WHERE year = PARTITION_DESCRIPTION);
```

This works, but it takes just as long as the full table scan. I also tried to do a partition select in the subquery but the syntax won't accept a user variable or a reference:

```
SELECT MAX(PARTITION_DESCRIPTION)
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS AS P
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'fact_registration'
        AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM fact_registration 
                   PARTITION(P.PARTITION_DESCRIPTION));  # syntax error, unexpected '.'
```

So, how can I eliminate the table scan and find the *accurate* maximum on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer to this was as simple as taking a closer look at [the columns in the  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitions-table.html):

> `TABLE_ROWS`: The number of table rows in the partition.
>
> For partitioned `InnoDB` tables, the row count given in the
>   `TABLE_ROWS` column is only an estimated value used in SQL
>   optimization, and may not always be exact.

So, for *the MyISAM engine in particular*, we can find the `MAX(year)` without a table scan or any additional indexing by using the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(PARTITION_DESCRIPTION) AS maxyear
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'fact_registration'
        AND TABLE_ROWS > 0;
```

**Note that this only works in certain situations** - if you have more than one value in a partition, the fact that there are rows in the partition doesn't necessarily mean that one or the other value is present; and since `PARTITION_DESCRIPTION` is a `longtext` column, the integer values you supply will be stored as a comma-separated string.